# SQLAlchemy: How to create a database entry with a enum field?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, sqlalchemy, model, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to define a sqlalchemy model with a enum field:

```
import enum

from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db.SQLAlchemy()

class Animal(enum.Enum):
     dog = "Dog"
     cat = "Cat"
     rabbit = "Rabbit"


class Child(db.models):
     __tablename__ = "child"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     animal = db.Column(db.Enum(Animal))
```

If I want to create a `Child` object, it works.

```
 child = Child(id=1, animal=Animal.dog)
```

But if want to get all entries like:

```
 childs = Child.query.all()
```

I get the error: `LookupError: 'Dog' is not among the defined enum values. Enum name: animal. Possible values: dog, cat, rabbit`.